# Problem applying setTimeout to await fetch() response

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I would like to know how to apply a `setTimeout` to my request response with await fetch. My code sends each response to a DIV in HTML, and I would like to know how to make it take 5 seconds for each response to appear.

**I tried this but I couldn't do it.**

```
const envSoli = async () => {
    try {
      const controller = new AbortController();
      const signal = controller.signal;
      const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();
      }, 20 * 1000); // 20 sec
      let peticion = await fetch("data.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        cache: "no-cache",
        signal: signal,
      });
      clearTimeout(timeId);
      const oreen = await peticion.json();
      const takeAMoment = setTimeout(() => {
        switch (oreen.enviando) {
            case -1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
      
            case 1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
      
            case 2:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
              nieva++;
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_dieUp();
              break;
      
            case 3:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
              tvmit_liveUp();
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              break;
          }
      
          OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
          return true;
      }, 5 * 1000);
      clearTimeout(takeAMoment);
  
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Swal.fire({
        text: translate("text2"),
        icon: "question",
        buttonsStyling: false,
        confirmButtonText: translate("confirmbtn"),
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
        },
        //refresh again on button click
      }).then(function () {
        location.reload();
      });
    }
  };
  envSoli();
```

### WORKING ORIGINAL CODE:

```
const envSoli = async () => {
  try {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      controller.abort();
    }, 20 * 1000);
    let peticion = await fetch("data.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      cache: "no-cache",
      signal: signal,
    });
    clearTimeout(timeId);
    let oreen = await peticion.json();

    switch (oreen.enviando) {
      case -1:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 1:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 2:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
        nieva++;
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_dieUp();
        break;

      case 3:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
        tvmit_liveUp();
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        break;
    }

    OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Swal.fire({
      text: translate("text2"),
      icon: "question",
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonText: translate("confirmbtn"),
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      allowEscapeKey: false,
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
      },
      //refresh again on button click
    }).then(function () {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
};
envSoli();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns immediately. It does not delay the execution of the next statement below it. So your code immediately cancels the `takeAMoment` timeout by clearing it in the very next statement.

In your scenario you already have a function declared with `async`, so use `await` when you want to delay the further execution of the function it is in.

Promisify `setTimeout` so you can use `await` with it:

```
// Promisify setTimeout:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

And then at the place where you assigned to `takeAMoment`, do:

```
        await delay(5 * 1000);
        switch (oreen.enviando) {
            // ...etc
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a queue. Create an array

```
var myQueue = [];
```

use push to add new updates

```
myQueue.push(update)
```

and then use setInterval and shift to pull one update every 5 seconds

```
setInterval(function() {
  var update = myQueue.shift();
  if (update) update();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: But I don't understand where in my code I should implement it :(

Comment: @SadDeepLoper You can create myQueue and call the setInterval in initial setup. myQueue.push should be called when you've got a new update (fetch result)